# Excel combining countifs and concatenate

Tags: excel-formula

[excel question with specific need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSnj5.png)

The description above describes my issue:
The formula

```
=COUNTIFS(GamesOUT!$D$2:$D$4377,$A2,GamesOUT!$G$2:$G$4377,">0",GamesOUT!$A$2:$A$4377,">20089999",GamesOUT!$A$2:$A$4377,"<20099999")
```

Needs:
In the above excel formula I want to replace the number “4377” with the value in cell B2.

Also I want to replace the number `20089999` with a formula calculating:

`(value in cell A2)*10000+9999`

Also I want to replace the number `20099999` with a formula calculating:

`[(value in cell A2)+1)]*10000+9999`

I cannot quite find a solution. A few stackoverflow posts dealt with this issue but the quotes within quotes in concatenate throw me for an "endless loop"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use *string concatenation* to compose your criteria parameters inside `COUNTIFS`:

```
=COUNTIFS(GamesOUT!$D$2:$D$4377, $A2,
          GamesOUT!$G$2:$G$4377, ">0",
          GamesOUT!$A$2:$A$4377, ">" & (A2*10000+9999),
          GamesOUT!$A$2:$A$4377, "<" & ((A2+1)*10000+9999))
```

What remains is to make your ranges extend dynamically until the row indicated by cell `B2`, you can use either `INDIRECT`, `OFFSET` or `INDEX`. The latter is preferred for being non-volatile: formula will recalculate only when its sources change. So you need to do some replacements:

`GamesOUT!$D$2:$D$4377`  --->  `GamesOUT!$D$2:INDEX(GamesOUT!$D:$D, B2)`

and similar for all the range parameters (that were "statically" ended by `4377`). It will be a pretty big formula but it will work.

```
=COUNTIFS(GamesOUT!$D$2:INDEX(GamesOUT!$D:$D, B2), $A2,
          GamesOUT!$G$2:INDEX(GamesOUT!$G:$G, B2), ">0",
          GamesOUT!$A$2:INDEX(GamesOUT!$A:$A, B2), ">" & (A2*10000+9999),
          GamesOUT!$A$2:INDEX(GamesOUT!$A:$A, B2), "<" & ((A2+1)*10000+9999))
```